# How to change color of very button in button arrays when i hover mouse to it in c# winform

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a button list which is a button array. Please tell me how to change the color of every button array button when I hover the mouse. I had tried to use loops in the event button when I used loop, but when I hover the mouse on the other button, this button still changes color although I never set any event for it.

Comment: Can you show your code? That will help to understand your question more clearly

Comment: Did you add these `Buttons` in the designer or create them in code? You only need one event handler and, in it, you act on the `sender`, which is the object that raised the event. You should register the handler for the event of each `Button` where you created the `Buttons`, i.e. in the designer or in code.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this code sample will be helpful to you

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private Button[] buttonsArray = null;
    
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        GetButtonsArray();

        if (buttonsArray != null)
        {
            foreach (Button button in buttonsArray)
            {
                button.MouseEnter += button_MouseEnter;
                button.MouseLeave += button_MouseLeave;
            }
        }
    }

    private void GetButtonsArray()
    {
        // This is an example to fill array of buttons. 
        // You have to fill array in your way, according to your task.

        foreach (Control control in this.Controls)
            if (control is Button)
                buttonsArray = buttonsArray.Append(control as Button);
    }
    
    private void button_MouseEnter(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (sender is Button)
            (sender as Button).BackColor = Color.Yellow;
    }

    private void button_MouseLeave(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (sender is Button)
            (sender as Button).BackColor = SystemColors.Control;
    }
}

public static class Extensions
{
    public static T[] Append<T>(this T[] array, T item)
    {
        if (array == null)
            return new T[] { item };
        
        T[] result = new T[array.Length + 1];
        array.CopyTo(result, 0);
        result[array.Length] = item;

        return result;
    }
}
```